# Unable to create Folder in SD Card in Android 6.0, Using Adobe Flex Code ANE Extension in Release mode

Tags: android, apache-flex, ane

This is Code to Create Folder inside a file in SD card in Android 6.0, Am using Flex Code , Added ANE Extension, AIR version 24.0 and swf = 35. working in debug Mode, But not working Release Mode. Please Help to me.

if(library.Utility.getDeviceType() == "ANDROID")
                {

```
                var permissionCheck : File; 
                permissionCheck  = new File(pdfFile.nativePath);
                permissionCheck.addEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS , function permissionStatusHandler( e : PermissionEvent ) :void
                {                        
                    permissionCheck.removeEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS , permissionStatusHandler);
                    if(e.status == PermissionStatus.GRANTED)
                    {                            
                        //  save your file
                        pdfFolder = File.userDirectory.resolvePath(".Folder");
                        if(!pdfFolder.exists)
                            pdfFolder.createDirectory();
                        trace(pdfFolder.nativePath);
                        //pdfFile =  File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("pdf/" +file);
                        var targetFile:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath(".Folder/" +file);
                        trace(targetFile.nativePath);
                        if(targetFile.exists)
                            targetFile.deleteFile();

                        if(!targetFile.exists && pdfFile.exists)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                pdfFile.copyTo(targetFile);
                                Template.showFile(targetFile.nativePath);
                            }
                            catch(error:Error)
                            {
                                Popup.showMessage("PDF Viewer", "Unable to open " + file + ". File does not exists. " + error.message);
                                trace("Error:" + error.message);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Popup.showMessage("PDF Viewer", "Unable to find " + file + ". File does not exists.");
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //showPermissionError();
                        trace("Error"+ pdfFolder.nativePath);

                    }

                });

                try
                {
                    permissionCheck.requestPermission();

                }
                catch(error : Error)
                {
                    trace("Error:" + error.message);
                }

            }
```

Comment: `This is Code to Create Folder inside a file in SD card` Well that is not possible. You cannot create a folder in a file. Nowhere.

Comment: `var permissionCheck : File; ` Which language is this?

Comment: Its is adobe Flex code

Comment: Well also adobe flex cannot create a folder in a file. Why dont you react?

Comment: In debug mode, folder  and inside pdf file is created Successfully,  but when i export to release mode that time app is not create folder in sd card.

Comment: Why app is working fine in debug mode,  not in release mode.????

Comment: Anything need to change in the code????

Comment: @greenapps I suspect a language barrier rather than "attempting the obviously impossible" here

Answer (score 2):

You should try to write your traces (like permission status, `pdfFolder.exists` and so on) into a `textField` so you can localize the problem in the release mode.

Also listen to `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` and `SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR` on your `targetFile` and trace them to the `textField`, maybe there are some problems with that.

Normally you should save the application files in the `File.applicationStorageDirectory` (and not in the `userDirectory`), but I guess you want the user to be able to access the files on his own?

Try a folder without the dot (`"Folder"` instead of `".Folder"`).

On Android you'll need to grant permissions for writing the files in your `application.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>             
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Logcat also helps with this kind of debugging.

Comment: Hi Philarmon and Brain, I have tested in all above steps. But in release mode "unable to create the Folder" means  "Template.showFile(targetFile.nativePath);"  methos not called.

Comment: I think in release mode, if(library.Utility.getDeviceType() == "ANDROID")   this is not calling...??

Comment: Right, Logcat is also awesome for spotting problems. @RajanKlsenter - what is this library you are using for Android detection? Try the native 
if(Platform.isAndroid)...

Comment: Thank you all, Issues Fixed.